# Extracting tag information with beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

Say I have some xml like

```
<item name=bread weight="5" edible="yes">
<body> some blah </body>
<item>

<item name=eggs weight="5" edible="yes">
<body> some blah </body>
<item>

<item name=meat weight="5" edible="yes">
<body> some blah </body>
<item>
```

I want to store the name of each item in a list using beautiful soup

Here's the attempt so far:

```
names =list()

for c in soup.findAll("item"):
    #get name from the tag
        names.append(name i got from tag)
```

This method has worked perfectly for extracting text between tags.

I've tried copying the methods used for extracting links `<a href="www.blah.com">` but it doesn't seem to work.

How would I store the name information in a list? (other lists contain the body text so for associativity reasons the indexes have to be consistent).

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `dict(item.attrs).get('name')` to get the name.

You are having issues since `<item>` is supposed to be a closing tag but it is an opening tag, hence you get 6 matches rather than 3. If you have any control over the text, please use closing tags to avoid this.

Here is the full snippet working as intended:

```
names = list()

for item in soup.findAll('item'):
    name = dict(item.attrs).get('name')
    if name is not None:
        names.append(name)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help @bossylobster : It was a typo not putting the closing tags in. can i omit "if name is not None:"

When I try to print out names[0] it just says "none".

Do you know why that is?

Comment: The line `if name is not None` is in there to account for occurrences where `dict(item.attrs).get('name')` returns `None`. This occur exactly when `'name'` is not a key in the `attrs` dictionary. If you only have a few items, you can inspect them by hand and discover why this occurs.