# Extracting tag attributes with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have been pulling my hair out all day with this. Basically I am unable to extract information from tags
like:

```
<REUTERS LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN">
```

I cannot get the value of LEWISSPLIT and store it in a list

I have the following code:

```
import arff
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import re
from StringIO import StringIO

import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

totstring=""

with open('reut2-000.sgm', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        string=re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z<>/\s=!-\"\"]+","", line)
    totstring+=string

soup = BeautifulSoup(totstring)

bodies = list()
topics = list()
tags = list()

for a in soup.findAll("body"):
    bodies.append(a)


for b in soup.findAll("topics"):
    topics.append(b)

for item in soup.findAll('REUTERS'):
    tags.append(item['TOPICS'])



outputstring=""

for x in range(0,len(bodies)):
    if topics[x].text=="":
        continue
    outputstring=outputstring+"<TOPICS>"+topics[x].text+"</TOPICS>\n"+"<BODY>"+bodies[x].text+"</BODY>\n"

outfile=open("output.sgm","w")
outfile.write(outputstring)

outfile.close()

print tags[0]

file.close
```

For parsing some old reuters XML that looks a little like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE lewis SYSTEM "lewis.dtd">
<REUTERS TOPICS="YES" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="5544" NEWID="1">
<DATE>26-FEB-1987 15:01:01.79</DATE>
<TOPICS><D>cocoa</D></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>el-salvador</D><D>usa</D><D>uruguay</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;C T
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0704&#31;reute
u f BC-BAHIA-COCOA-REVIEW   02-26 0105</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>BAHIA COCOA REVIEW</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    SALVADOR, Feb 26 - </DATELINE><BODY>Showers continued throughout the week in
the Bahia cocoa zone, alleviating the drought since early
January and improving prospects for the coming temporao,
although normal humidity levels have not been restored,
Comissaria Smith said in its weekly review.
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
<REUTERS TOPICS="NO" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="5545" NEWID="2">
<DATE>26-FEB-1987 15:02:20.00</DATE>
<TOPICS></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>usa</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;F Y
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0708&#31;reute
d f BC-STANDARD-OIL-&lt;SRD>-TO   02-26 0082</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>STANDARD OIL &lt;SRD> TO FORM FINANCIAL UNIT</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    CLEVELAND, Feb 26 - </DATELINE><BODY>Standard Oil Co and BP North America
Inc said they plan to form a venture to manage the money market
borrowing and investment activities of both companies.
    BP North America is a subsidiary of British Petroleum Co
Plc &lt;BP>, which also owns a 55 pct interest in Standard Oil.
    The venture will be called BP/Standard Financial Trading
and will be operated by Standard Oil under the oversight of a
joint management committee.
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
<REUTERS TOPICS="NO" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="5546" NEWID="3">
<DATE>26-FEB-1987 15:03:27.51</DATE>
<TOPICS></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>usa</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;F A
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0714&#31;reute
d f BC-TEXAS-COMMERCE-BANCSH   02-26 0064</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>TEXAS COMMERCE BANCSHARES &lt;TCB> FILES PLAN</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    HOUSTON, Feb 26 - </DATELINE><BODY>Texas Commerce Bancshares Inc's Texas
Commerce Bank-Houston said it filed an application with the
Comptroller of the Currency in an effort to create the largest
banking network in Harris County.
    The bank said the network would link 31 banks having
13.5 billion dlrs in assets and 7.5 billion dlrs in deposits.

 Reuter
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
```

I am interested in removing special characters, extracting both the content of the body and topic tags and building new xml out of them:

```
<topic>oil</topic>
<body>asdsd</body>
<topic>grain</topic>
<body>asdsdds</body>
```

I want to split this data based upon the value of `LEWISSPLIT`

I have been able to do all of this so far apart from split it on the value of lewissplit.

This is because I CANNOT extract the value from the `<reuters>` tag. I have tried many different techniques from this website and the official documentation but when running

```
for item in soup.findAll('REUTERS'):
    tags.append(item['LEWISSPLIT'])

print tags[0]
```

all i get is []

Why on earth is it so hard to extract the value of the LEWISSPLIT attribute from the `<REUTERS>` tag?

Thanks so much for reading this.

See also [Extracting tag information with beautifulsoup and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521443/extracting-tag-information-with-beautifulsoup-and-python)

Comment: What happens when you call `soup.findAll('REUTERS')`? What kind of output do you get? Have you tried `soup.findAll('reuters')`? I noticed that when I parsed the xml you provided, BeautifulSoup converted all the tags to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Cornett is correct,

"reuters" along with "lewissplit" should have been in lower case :( Correct syntax:

```
for item in soup.findAll('reuters'):
    tags.append(item['lewissplit'])
```